# Count rows and export based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

So I have an Excel file, that I want to export some of the rows to another Excel file, my problem is that I have a row that is like:

```
1    
1    
1    
2    
2    
2    
3    
3    
3    
1   
1    
1
```

And I want to export from the first row with number one to the last row with number 3, and after exportation delete that same lines.

So far i have this.

```
Private Sub export2()
folha = exportform.Label14.Caption
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Dim src As Workbook

' ABRIR EXCEL
Set src = Workbooks.Open("U:\Mecânica\Produção\OEE\OEE ( FULL LOG )\FRS\FRS_DADOS.xlsx", True, False)
WS_Count = src.Worksheets.Count
 For o = 1 To WS_Count
 src.Worksheets(o).Unprotect password:="registoOEE"
 Next o

lastsrc = src.Worksheets("DADOS").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
last = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(folha).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row




Dim last, I As Integer
Dim turno As String

Sheets(folha).Select

For I = 2 To last
'If application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(folha).Cells(last, 61)














Next I




ErrHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True







  For o = 1 To WS_Count
 src.Worksheets(o).Protect password:="registoOEE"
 Next o


  Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'IT WORKS TO DISABLE ALERT PROMPT

  'SAVES FILE USING THE VARIABLE BOOKNAME AS FILENAME
 src.Save

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'RESETS DISPLAY ALERTS

' CLOSE THE SOURCE FILE.
src.Close True             ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE.
Set src = Nothing


fim:
End Sub
```

I've edited so you can see what code i have already, hope it helps.

Comment: Please add the code you already have and explain in a detailed way where you are stuck. This will allow us to provide a decent answer. Regards,

Comment: I have only the code to open the other excel file , after that i'm missing all the code that i need to do what i want

Comment: People will be willing to help if you could show that you have researched and tried yourself. Look up "last row" to begin with.. look up "delete rows".. do some research,  post your code and we can go from there.

Comment: Ok , i've edited the post and pasted the code that i have in right now, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this 10 months old question as it might help someone who is still searching for similar kind of results.

I have put a count if formula in AI column to count the number of occurrences of value in AH and if the the AI value is greater than 1 the same will be pasted in different sheet.

Here is the code:

```
    Sub CopyDups()
       With Application
         .ScreenUpdating = False
         .EnableEvents = False
       End With

    Dim cnt As Range
    Dim nu As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SourceData")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Criteria 1")

    nu = 1     
    For Each cnt In Source.Range("AI1:AI1000")   
      If cnt > 1 Then
        Source.Rows(cnt.Row).Copy Target.Rows(nu)
        nu = nu + 1
      End If
    Next cnt
       With Application
         .ScreenUpdating = True
         .EnableEvents = True
       End With
    End Sub
```